# margin left messing the alignment of the layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment, centering

So i basically have a simple header , it has `header__left` , `header__middle` and `header__right` ,they are all wrapped inside a wrapper `div` and i have my content in header__left and header__right but in the header__middle i have a ``ul`and`li`items now they are junmpled together so if i use`margin right`or left on them i think it messes the`alignment``` of the page loggically i know it makes sense that things wont be center anymore but i dont know any other way,so what is the more cleaner way?

```css
body{

    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #2c3e50;
}


header{
    background: white;
}

.wrapper{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

.header__middle ul{
    
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;

}

.header__middle ul li a{


    margin-right: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;


}






.header__right h1{

    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0,1);
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;

}

.header__right h1 a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    transition: 0.3s ease all;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="header__left">
                <h1>KYOSK</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="header__middle">
                <ul>
                    <li ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Join</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="header__right">
                <h1><a href="#">Contact Us</a></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Made some corrections to your css. I think it would be prettier.

```css
body{

    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #2c3e50;
}


header{
    background: white;
}

.wrapper{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

.header__middle ul{
    
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0;

}

.header__middle ul li {


    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.2em;
   
    text-align: center;


}

    .header__middle ul li a {
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #000;
     }






.header__right h1{

    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0,1);
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;

}

.header__right h1 a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    transition: 0.3s ease all;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="header__left">
                <h1>KYOSK</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="header__middle">
                <ul>
                    <li ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Join</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="header__right">
                <h1><a href="#">Contact Us</a></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```